# JavaFX disableProperty with two conditions not working

Tags: binding, javafx

I have a problem with

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable {
    @FXML protected Button loginButton;
    @FXML protected TextField email;
    @FXML protected PasswordField password;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        loginButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.and(email.textProperty().isEmpty(), password.textProperty().isEmpty()));
    }
}
```

The LoginButton shall be disabled until both fields, email and password, are not empty...

At the moment, the LoginButton is enabled, when I enter one character in either field, leaving the other field alone...

Any ideas, where I got my mistake?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OR`:

```
loginButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.or(email.textProperty().isEmpty(), password.textProperty().isEmpty()));
```

Comment: Damn... Too easy... Thanks...